# How Can I Return a Random Object in Loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback to build an application, and would like to write a custom remote method which returns a random model instance from the database.

Is there a way to do this using the built-in ORM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way. You can do it manually depending on the type of data source you're using.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/loopbackjs/random/loopbackjs/C08v1K0NKHk/8nUp9VSGEhEJ

Comment: Thanks! Would be cool to get random() stuff added into the ORM, but that's a totally non-SO related thingy ^^

Comment: Feel free to submit a feature request. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Reporting-issues#featureenhancement-request